# How can I split a word into its component letters?

Tags: perl

I am working with Perl and I have an array with only one word:

```
@example = ("helloword")
```

I want to generate another array in which each element is a letter from the word:

```
@example2 = ("h", "e", "l"...)
```

I need to do that because I need to count the numbers of "h", "e"... How can I do this?

Comment: You need to count the number of letters in the word, or you need to count the number of `h`s in the word?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To count how many times letter occurred in a string,

```
print "helloword" =~ tr/h//; # for 'h' letter
```

otherwise you can split string and assign list to an array,

```
my @example2 = split //, $example[0];
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't completely grasp exactly what you need to count, but perhaps you can take pieces from this example, which uses a hash to store the letters and counts of each...

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @array = 'helloworld';

my %letters;
$letters{$_}++ for split //, $array[0];

my $total;

while (my ($k, $v) = each %letters){
    $total += $v;
    print "$k: $v\n";
}
print "Total letters in string: $total\n",
```

Output:

```
    w: 1
    d: 1
    l: 3
    o: 2
    e: 1
    r: 1
    h: 1
    Total letters in string: 10
```

Comment: can you explain this line: $letters{$_}++ for split //, $array[0];

Answer (score 3):

Try using this code, found here: http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/Perl/split.html

`@chars = split(//, $word);`

Answer (score 0):

You can of course use `split(//,"helloworld")`, but that's not as efficient as unpack. Figuring out the template to provide to unpack can be somewhat steep, but this should work for you: `unpack('(A)*',"helloworld")`. For example:

```
perl -e 'print(join("\n",unpack("(A)*","helloworld")),"\n")'
h
e
l
l
o
w
o
r
l
d
```

To count the number of letters, you could either assume that every character of a "word" you split the string up into is a letter and simply evaluate the list in scalar context (or use 'length'), e.g. `print(scalar(@letters),"\n");` or `print(length(@letters),"\n")`, OR you could create a count variable and increment it in a map when a letter pattern is matched, e.g.:

```
my $cnt = 0;
foreach(@chars){$cnt++ if(/\w/)}
print("$cnt\n");
```

Or you can use the same evaluation of a list in scalar trick with a grep:

```
print(scalar(grep {/\w/} @chars),"\n");
```

There are of course, in perl, other ways to do it.

EDIT: In case I misinterpreted the question, and you want to know how many of each letter there is in the string, then this should suffice:

```
$cnt = 0;
foreach(unpack("(A)*","helloworld")))
  {
    next unless(/\w/);
    $hash->{$_}->{ORD} = $cnt++ unless(exists($hash->{$_}));
    $hash->{$_}->{CNT}++;
  }

foreach(sort {$hash->{$a}->{ORD} <=> $hash->{$b}->{ORD}}
        keys(%$hash))
  {print("$_\t$hash->{$_}->{CNT}\n")}
```

This solution has the advantage of keeping the unique letters in the order of their first occurrence in the word they were found in.

Comment: Did you happen to `Benchmark` the two? I did, and `split` turned out to be significantly more efficient. Perhaps `unpack` alone is faster, but that alone doesn't give the OP what is needed.

Comment: I concur with @stevieb's benchmark, with the addition that code clarity is usually more important than performance anyway. (On my humble VM, both `split` and `unpack` can split a 10,000-character string hundreds of times per second.) Also, `map` in void context is usually clearer as a `for` loop.

Comment: I've benchmarked unpack versus split in other contexts with long DNA strings and unpack was faster, so it could depend on string length. But we don't know if the OP is dealing with huge strings or not. All we got was the helloworld example. So it's still a valid suggestion with that caveat. I'll concede that split is definitely more readable, which is the main reason unpack has fallen into disfavor. Why doesn't my suggestion give the OP what is needed?

Comment: I think I see what you mean about giving the OP what they want. The question is unclear. I interpreted it to mean the total number of letters in the word as opposed to the number of h's, e's, etc..